# Xcode debug console cut off

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, xcode4

When debugging my C++ app in Xcode 4 with the iOS simulator, the debug console gets cut off abruptly with the message "[Switching to process 45196 thread 0x207]", and that's it, no more output.  The app carries on running as normal, so it's clearly an Xcode/gdb interaction thing, not a code problem.

Any suggestions for getting my console back?

**Update:** it still happens with Xcode 4.0.2

Comment: I also had the same problem with the latest iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What fixed it for me is that my C++ code was calling some Objective-C methods. These methods also had some printing to the console. Note that this objective-C code also manages some threads (for AudioUnits). When I commented out every print statement (doest mather if they are printf or NSlog) then all the rest printed correctlty to sonsole. So is it thread, the C++, objective-C mix or something else ---Your Guess--- but it did the trick